# How to handle CollectionFS saving failures

Tags: meteor

I'm using collectionFS and in particular the S3 storage adapter.

Most files get uploaded perfectly fine and I can download them afterwards with no problem.

Occasionally I get a file that appears to load fine (`Files.insert(blob,callback)` returns to the callback with no error) but later when I go to download them `fsFile.url()` returns `null`.

https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#after-the-upload says:

> If any storage adapters fail to save any of the copies in the designated store, the server will periodically retry saving them. After a configurable number of failed attempts at saving, the server will give up.

But there is no callback that I'm aware of for such a failure. Furthermore when looking at `fsFile.uploadProgress()` I get 100%.

The basic problem is thus that during upload everything looks fine and my app only detects a problem when trying to download the file.

1. Is there a way to detect an upload failure in the storage adapter?
2. What else would `fsFile.url()` returning `null` be symptomatic of?

Here's an example of one of these *broken* fsFile objects in mongodb:

```
{
  "_id" : "uqAYajqCv68HmEJhu",
  "original" : {
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-03-16T23:04:37.200Z"),
    "size" : 699072,
    "type" : ""
    },
  "chunkSize" : 2097152,
  "chunkCount" : 0,
  "chunkSum" : 1,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the new version of FScollection, there was integrated 3 events on the `server` side, `stored`,`uploaded` and `error`.

```
Images.on('error', function (fileObj) {
      console.log("The " + fileObj + " with the _id " + fileObj._id " + just get an error when uploading")
    });
```

There is not documentation about this, since raix and aldeed clean the README.

Comment: Thanks Ethaan, let me see what I can do with that.

Comment: @MichelFloyd did you get it?

Comment: I'm using `Files.on('uploaded',function(fileObj){});` and am indeed seeing callbacks on the server, thanks!! We upped retries to 20 so we haven't seen `on('error')` fire yet.

Comment: @Michel Floyd awesome, feel free to upvote or accept the answer to help newcomers with similar issues

Comment: Do you know hot to handle this on client side?